# Service stack from a web application

Tags: servicestack

I was looking at integrating a class library that uses service stack with an existing web application. I added the class library and its reference dlls in the bin folder for the web application and entries in the `web.config` file for dependency injection but I am getting an error as below. Please let me know the best way to approach this issue.

> error: ServiceStack: AppHost does not exist or has not been initialized. Make sure you have created an AppHost and started it with 'new AppHost().Init();' in your Global.asax Application_Start() or alternative Application StartUp

Answer (score 1):

Go through [Creating your first web service from scratch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) to walk through how to add ServiceStack to an empty ASP.NET Web Application.

[AppHost is your own class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice#step-4-registering-your-web-services-and-starting-your-application) that you create that inherits `AppHostBase`.

You should get the .dlls from the [ServiceStack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack) NuGet package, but otherwise you never want to put dlls in `/bin` folder yourself, if you instead want to reference a copy of the ServiceStack dlls they should be in an external folder like `/lib`, when VS.NET builds your project it will automatically copy it to the `/bin` folder.

I would still recommend using the NuGet packages, but if you want to reference .dlls have a look at the [Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat) demo which references copy of ServiceStack dlls in custom `/lib` folder, it also has the [minimal libs required](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat#super-lean-front-and-back) for a ServiceStack + Razor ASP.NET Web Application.

Comment: Thanks for response I followed the link and added apphost, but it is giving another error. Not sure what it could be. {"Error trying to resolve Service ....interface.IBuilder' or one of its autowired dependencies (see inner exception for details)."}    {"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. "}

Comment: @ServiceStacktest you're going to have to provide more code/error details, `IBuilder` is not a class in ServiceStack, I'd strip your App down to the bare basics and carefully add back code till you know what's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do what the error description suggested? Go into `global.asax.cs`, and add:

```
new AppHost().Init();
```

into the `Application_Start()` method.

Comment: @Phani How does this not attempt to provide an answer? It might be completely wrong, [but that doesn't mean we should delete it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664) Please pay attention when reviewing.

Comment: @Undo When you are not sure, its best to confirm/comment on question before adding as an answer. After the confirmation, yes, it is considered as an answer.